# Unable to stop signin with google-plus

Tags: javascript, google-plus

I am using below script to get user authenticated via google, it works fine but the problem is, with out click on g+ signin button it taks the google session from browser and authenticates the user. how to make it on buttion click.

```
(function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script');
    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
```

Is there any way to run this function on button click.?

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use Google Javascript Api.

```
<a id="googleLogin"> Login with Google</a>

<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=handleClientLoad"></>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#googleLogin").bind("click", function(){
    gapi.auth.authorize({client_id: YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, 
      immediate: false,
      scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email"
    }, function(authResult){
          YOUR CODE HERE 
       });
  });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML

`<input id="authBtn" type="button" value="authenticate me"/>`

JS

```
document.getElementById("authBtn").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var po = document.createElement('script');

    po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://plus.google.com/js/client:plusone.js';

    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
});
```

Comment: its stopping the automatic authentication, but its not allowing to authenticate user on click also.